# Trapdoor: which first, frame or floor?

Tags: doors, flooring

I'm installing a trapdoor to provide easier access to the basement. This is the first step in a kitchen renovation so I've also taken up the laminate flooring. The hole for the trapdoor is already done.

My question is - given that I'm going to lay the laminate flooring again - which should come first, installing a frame for the trapdoor or laying the laminate floor? Will it be easier to install the frame and then lay the laminate floor around it, or do the flooring first, leaving enough space to install the frame afterwards?

n.b. I will be attaching the frame to the subfloor rather than onto the laminate flooring itself (otherwise the point would be moot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that since you intend (and should) attach the frame to the subfloor that it will be much better to install the frame first. Then fit the flooring up to the frame.